# Where does the pain from headaches come from

Tags: human-biology, pain

I may be wrong but I have always thought that the brain doesnt have any nerve endings, so why is it we get headaches and where does this pain come from?

I have heard lack of sleep, hydration or stress can causes headaches but I am interested in why and where the pain comes from this.

Comment: I knew it would be somewhere, I just couldnt find it .. Thanks